# How do you wipe your hands in Nethack?

Tags: nethack

I opened a tin can and ate something with my hands, which made them greasy. Now holding a weapon is impossible, and so is wearing rings. I tried #wipe but it seems that's only for the face. How would I wipe my hands?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to find a *towel* and apply it.

If you lack a towel, the effect should go away in due time without you needing to do anything. According to [Wooble](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3243/wooble) in the comments, this is specifically *up to 15 turns*.

Comment: The slippery hands effect lasts up to 15 turns, which really isn't all that horrible most of the time.